# Groovy passes boxed types to Jenkins, how to unbox?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a Jenkins pipeline that would restart Jenkins once a week if no jobs are running. Since I don't want to block running jobs for too long, I'm trying to call `doQuietDown` with the timeout argument.

https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#doQuietDown-boolean-int-

So that's what I'm trying:

```
        stage('Quiet Down') {
            steps {
                script {
                    boolean doBlock = true
                    int timeout_ms = 30000
                    Jenkins.doQuietDown(doBlock, timeout_ms)
                }
            }
        }
```

That fails:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static jenkins.model.Jenkins.doQuietDown() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Integer) values: [true, 30000]
Possible solutions: doQuietDown(boolean, int), doQuietDown()
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1501)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1487)
```

So groovy is passing boxed types, but Jenkins expects unboxed types. I tried casts to unboxed types, `booleanValue()` and `intValue()`, using `true` and `30000` without variables, but all that made no difference to the error message.

I also tried `Jenkins.doQuietDown block: doBlock, timeout: timeout_ms` but it's passing `LinkedHashMap`:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.doQuietDown() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[block:true, timeout:30000]]
```

I'm using Jenkins 2.180 (the current version at the time of this posting)

Comment: It's not a static method. And you call it as a static. You have to do something like `Jenkins.get().doQuietDown(...)`. Boxing/unboxing - groovy do it automatically.

Comment: @daggert You are right, that was it! The message was confusing. Please feel free to post your comment as a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a static method. And you call it as a static.

You have to do something like `Jenkins.get().doQuietDown(...)`.

Boxing/unboxing - groovy do it automatically.